# Increase performance of Map painting and filtering - Angular 8, LeafletJS

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, leaflet

I have a leafletjs map that has 8,200 circle markers on it. I have 8 mat-selection-lists with values off to the side. The basic thought is you choose a value and then it filters the markers based on the selection.

Everything works just fine, the problem is the performance isn't the greatest; for loading the screen and for also doing the filtering.

The angular component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectionList, MatSelectionListChange } from '@angular/material';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

import stores from 'src/assets/stores.json';
import filterTestStores from 'src/assets/filter-stores.json';
import filterTestRegions from 'src/assets/filter-regions.json';
import filterTestCities from 'src/assets/filter-cities.json';
import filterTestStates from 'src/assets/filter-states.json';
import filterTestRaces from 'src/assets/filter-races.json';
import filterTestAreas from 'src/assets/filter-urban.json';
import filterTestSeasons from 'src/assets/filter-season.json';
import filterTestPlanograms from 'src/assets/filter-planogram.json';
import filterTestTimes from 'src/assets/filter-time.json';

declare var $: any;
declare let L;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-location',
  templateUrl: './test-location.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-location.component.scss']
})
export class TestLocationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('regions', {static: false}) regions: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('states', {static: false}) states: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('cities', {static: false}) cities: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('races', {static: false}) races: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('areas', {static: false}) areas: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('seasons', {static: false}) seasons: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('planograms', {static: false}) planograms: MatSelectionList;
  @ViewChild('times', {static: false}) times: MatSelectionList;

  constructor(public _dataService: DataService) {

  }

  map: any;
  markers: any;
  defaultMarkerGroup: any;
  showDefault = true;
  testFilterMarkerGroup: any;
  myRenderer: any;

  regionsList: string[] = filterTestRegions
  statesList: string[] = filterTestStates
  cityList: string[] = filterTestCities;
  storeList: number[] = filterTestStores;
  racesList: string[] = filterTestRaces;
  areasList: string[] = filterTestAreas;
  seasonsList: string[] = filterTestSeasons;
  planogramsList: string[] = filterTestPlanograms;
  timesList: string[] = filterTestTimes;

  removeDuplicates(myArr, prop) {
    return myArr.filter((obj, pos, arr) => {
      return arr.map(mapObj => mapObj[prop]).indexOf(obj[prop]) === pos;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("regionsList", this.regions.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("statesList", this.states.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("citiesList", this.cities.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("racesList", this.races.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("areasList", this.areas.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("seasonsList", this.seasons.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("planogramsList", this.planograms.selectedOptions.selected);
    this._dataService.setSelectedMapList("timesList", this.times.selectedOptions.selected);

    this._dataService.setSameLocationArea(true);

    if(this.showDefault) {
      this._dataService.setUniverseSize(this.defaultMarkerGroup.getLayers().length);
    } else {
      this._dataService.setUniverseSize(this.testFilterMarkerGroup.getLayers().length);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.regionsList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "MARKET UNIT");
    // this.filteredRegions = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "MARKET UNIT");
    // this.statesList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "State Abbreviation");
    // this.cityList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "CITY");
    // this.racesList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "Race");
    // this.areasList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "Urbanicity");
    // this.seasonsList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "Seasonality");
    // this.planogramsList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "Planogram");
    // this.timesList = this.removeDuplicates(stores, "Time Open");


    this.map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    this.myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.2 });

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      id: 'mapbox.light',
      accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY29sdHN0cmVldCIsImEiOiJjanFjZmZsODIwcDNoNDJud3gzMjI4OGF4In0.h9uLyByXir4aaTDxRxleiA'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    // setup a marker group
    this.defaultMarkerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map);

    //Apply Markers
    for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
      L.circleMarker([stores[i].LATITUDE, stores[i].LONGITUDE], {
        radius: 5,
        color: "green",
        renderer: this.myRenderer
      }).addTo(this.defaultMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
    }


    let svc = this;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // svc.regions.selectAll();
      // svc.states.selectAll();
      // svc.cities.selectAll();
      // svc.races.selectAll();
    });

    this.map.fitBounds(this.defaultMarkerGroup.getBounds());
  }

  clearStoreMarkers() {
    this.map.removeLayer(this.testFilterMarkerGroup);
    this.map.addLayer(this.defaultMarkerGroup);
    this.showDefault = true;

    this.regions.deselectAll();
    this.states.deselectAll();
    this.cities.deselectAll();
    this.races.deselectAll();
    this.areas.deselectAll();
    this.seasons.deselectAll();
    this.planograms.deselectAll();
    this.times.deselectAll();
  }

  filterMarkers() {
    this.map.removeLayer(this.defaultMarkerGroup);
    if (this.testFilterMarkerGroup) {
      this.map.removeLayer(this.testFilterMarkerGroup);
    }

    // setup a marker group
    this.testFilterMarkerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map);

    if (this.regions.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.states.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.cities.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.races.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.areas.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.seasons.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.planograms.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0 &&
      this.times.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0) {

      this.map.addLayer(this.defaultMarkerGroup);
      this.showDefault = true;
      this.map.fitBounds(this.defaultMarkerGroup.getBounds());
    } else { //Apply Markers
      this.showDefault = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
        let store = stores[i];

        this.regions.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["MARKET UNIT"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.states.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["State Abbreviation"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.cities.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["CITY"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.races.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["Race"]["Ethnicity"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.areas.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["Urbanicity"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.seasons.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["Seasonality"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.planograms.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["Planogram"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });

        this.times.selectedOptions.selected.forEach((selection: any, key: any) => {
          if (store["Time Open"].toLowerCase() === selection.value.toLowerCase()) {
            //Add Marker
            L.circleMarker([store.LATITUDE, store.LONGITUDE], {
              radius: 5,
              color: "green",
              renderer: this.myRenderer
            }).addTo(this.testFilterMarkerGroup).bindPopup('marker ' + i);
          }
        });
      }
      this.map.fitBounds(this.testFilterMarkerGroup.getBounds());
    }
  }

  selectAll(filter) {
    filter.selectAll();
    this.filterMarkers();
  }

  deselectAll(filter) {
    filter.deselectAll();
    this.filterMarkers();
  }

  onSelection(evt, property) {
    // this.filteredRegions = [];
    // if (evt.option.selectionList.selectedOptions.selected.length === 0) {
    //   this.filteredRegions.push(...this.regionsList);
    // } else {

    //   this.filteredRegions = stores.filter(function (region) {
    //     return region[property] === evt.option.value;
    //   });
    //   this.filteredRegions = this.removeDuplicates(this.filteredRegions, "MARKET UNIT");
    // }

    this.filterMarkers();
  }

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<mat-toolbar class="header">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <a mat-icon-button matTooltip="Back to Step 3" routerLink="/stepThree" routerLinkActive="active">
      <i class="far fa-caret-square-left fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="header-img">
      <img src="/assets/images/Dollar_Tree_logo.png">
    </div>
    <img class="dv-logo" src="/assets/images/DV-Transparent.png">
    <!-- <span class="spacer"></span> -->
    <a mat-icon-button matTooltip="Review and Submit" routerLink="/review" routerLinkActive="active">
      <i class="far fa-caret-square-right fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="col-12 p-0 step-header">
  <button mat-icon-button class="export-button" matTooltip="Export Selected Stores">
    <i class="fas fa-share"></i>
  </button>
  <div>Test & Control Universe Selection</div>
  <button mat-icon-button class="export-all-button" matTooltip="Export All Stores">
    <i class="fas fa-share-square"></i>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="row filter-bk">
  <div class="col-md-3 text-center store-filter-content">
    <button mat-raised-button class="mt-1" (click)="clearStoreMarkers()">Reset</button>
    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>Region</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #regions (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, 'MARKET UNIT')">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let region of regionsList" [value]='region'>
          <span>{{region}}</span>
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>State</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #states (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, 'State Abbreviation')">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let state of statesList" [value]='state'>
          {{state}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>City</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #cities (selectionChange)="onSelection()">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let city of cityList" [value]='city'>
          {{city}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>Race/Ethnicity</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #races (selectionChange)="onSelection()">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let race of racesList" [value]='race'>
          {{race}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>Urbanicity</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #areas (selectionChange)="onSelection()">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let area of areasList" [value]='area'>
          {{area}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>Seasonality</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #seasons (selectionChange)="onSelection()">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let season of seasonsList" [value]='season'>
          {{season}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>Planogram</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #planograms (selectionChange)="onSelection($event, 'Planogram')">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let planogram of planogramsList" [value]='planogram'>
          {{planogram}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card class="filter-section">
      <div>Store Open Duration</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-selection-list #times (selectionChange)="onSelection()">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let time of timesList" [value]='time'>
          {{time}}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 p-0 m-0">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start looking into https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy and https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

There is an example of how to use the change detection strategy and change detection ref in the second link. Try it and let us know whether it helps with the performance issue or not.